# .NET Core 2 MVC - Not loading on HTTP, does load on HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-express

I am working on an API in .NET core 2.

Everything works great when testing on `https://localhost:44333`, but when trying on `http://localhost:44333` it does not work anymore. It just loads, and loads, and loads.... Nothing to see in the logs or anything like that.

The thing is, I need to get it working on `HTTP` because I want to try it on my phone in the app. So I use [iisexpress-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy) to proxy it. This works when I can access the API on HTTP, but it doesn't work with HTTPS.

So therefor I need it to work with `HTTP`, but I have no idea why it does not work on `HTTP`. All my previous projects worked fine on `HTTP` and for some reason this one does not. I have looked in my startup if it might be forced or something like that, but I cannot find any...

You probably need more information than this, but I don't know what you need, so If you ask in the comments I will provide some more information/logs/code you name it.

Comment: In this particular case the port was the same, but even with two different ports it is worth checking the actual error. It might be the case that given port is blocked from HTTP usage. Additional reading: https://jazzy.id.au/2012/08/23/why_does_chrome_consider_some_ports_unsafe.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `http` version will be served on a different port. You'll need to look at your project properties to see which port it's being served on.

Just as some background:

There's effectively a client-side and server-side component to SSL. The `http` or `https` is the client-side component. That means the browser or other web client will either try to negotiate a secure socket or not, respectively. The server-side component is the port binding, which will either be a secure socket or not.

The forever-loading is because your client is trying to make a non-secure request, but the server's socket is attempting to negotiate SSL. It's like one person speaking Chinese and the other speaking Spanish. They're both communicating, but nothing gets accomplished.